# North Cyprus visa for Travel Document holder

Tags: visas, northern-cyprus

Do you need a visa to visit north Cyprus for a Palestinian holding an Egypt passport/ travel document?

Comment: To be clear, this is for the holder of an Egyptian travel document and not an Egyptian passport, right? In other words, you are not also an Egyptian citizen?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, [you do not need a visa for Northern Cyprus](http://mfa.gov.ct.tr/consular-info/visa-regulations/). In addition, if your journey is on a single ticket (such as with Turkish Airlines or Pegasus), [you also do not need a visa for Turkey](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=tr&SECTION=vi&SUBSECTION=tw&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C).